# How to run command in windows batch Command in jenkins

Tags: batch-file, hudson, jenkins

I am trying to run a command in Jenkins under build step of running commands in  Execute windows batch command.

I wrote dir  to run as a command

and when the job runs in Jenkins which is triggered by a change in content of a file  following error is shown

```
[FSTrigger] Triggered by a change to a file (<a href="triggerCauseAction">log</a>)
Building in workspace C:\Users\Pankaj\.jenkins\jobs\convert File to text form\workspace
FATAL: null
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap.buildFromSorted(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap.buildFromSorted(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap.buildFromSorted(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap.buildFromSorted(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap.buildFromSorted(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap.buildFromSorted(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TreeMap.putAll(Unknown Source)
at hudson.EnvVars.<init>(EnvVars.java:82)
at hudson.EnvVars$GetEnvVars.call(EnvVars.java:207)
at hudson.EnvVars$GetEnvVars.call(EnvVars.java:205)
at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)
at hudson.EnvVars.getRemote(EnvVars.java:202)
at hudson.model.Computer.getEnvironment(Computer.java:837)
at hudson.model.Run.getEnvironment(Run.java:1883)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getEnvironment(AbstractBuild.java:836)
at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:75)
at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:58)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:710)
at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.build(Build.java:178)
at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.doRun(Build.java:139)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:480)
at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1434)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:239)
```

Please see to this issue.

Comment: If you remove the windows batch step, do you still get this message?

Comment: yes i am getting the same message again.

Comment: then it is not about the windows command you added... you have a different problem.
try creating a new job and add one step at a time and then check which one causes this error

Comment: Ya i created a new job and i added a single command in it . but it was showing the same error ...And one more thing i haven't installed the windows as a service in JENKINS.

Comment: did you get any job to work?
you might have a problem with the installation, try reinstalling it in case nothing worked so far

Comment: I found the Answer..Actually i haven't installed Windows as a service in Jenkins. So for this we need to go to "manage Jenkins" and then click on  "windows as a service".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this question:
Actually i haven't installed Windows as a service in Jenkins. So for this we need to go to "manage Jenkins" and then click on "windows as a service".I.e Installing Jenkins as  a windows service.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you need to install Jenkins as a Windows service to execute a batch command as a build step. What might be an issue is that on Windows, commands such as `dir` are internal to the command interpreter (i.e. `cmd.exe`). In short, it means that in a Java program you cannot simply run the internal `dir` command using the `java.lang.Runtime.exec("dir")` method because there is no such a program as `dir.exe` (on your `PATH`). What you should do is execute the command interpreter itself and specify the internal command as a parameter, i.e. `java.lang.Runtime.exec("cmd /C dir")`.
Having that said and being aware that Jenkins is a Java application, it's better to use `cmd /C dir` instead of just typing `dir` in Jenkins' job configuration. Internally, Jenkins might use some 3rd pary libraries for executing external processes, such as Apache Commons Exec (see http://commons.apache.org/exec/), which hide the details between internal command(s) and "normal" commands, but from my experience it's not the case for all releases - especially the old ones.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..but how did it worked when i installed Jenkins as  a windows service.Because when it was not installed the error pops ups every time and now after installation as a service everything is fine.

Comment: Actually it's a good question. Could you tell me which version of Jenkins are you using? I have the latest one on my box and cannot replicate the issue you've found.

Comment: Currently i am using the latest version of jenkins.